how to create a foreign key from the top model to bottom model?
class Model1(models.Model):
x = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Model2(models.Model):
y = models.CharField(max_length=200)

How to create a foreign key to Model2 from Model1?
I know maybe you say you just need to replace Model1 with Model2 and then create a foreign key, but sometimes like now I need to do something like this.

You can use a manytomany field if that is what you mean.

models.ForeignKey('Model2', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

You can use a string literal of the form 'app_name.ModelName' if the identifier of the model class is not (yet) in scope, or even 'ModelName' if it is defined in the same app, so:
class Model1(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey('Model2', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Model2(models.Model):
    y = models.CharField(max_length=200)
